# Apache Sqoop is not getting installed properly in Mac OS

Tags: macos, hadoop, sqoop

I am setting up sqoop in my MAC OS and found the problem that sqoop help is throwing -bash: command not found problem.
What I did here I will brief -

1. Setup Hadoop , ran the same and it worked properly, for that I as well set HADOOP_HOME in bash_profile
2. Setup HIVE and set the same HIVE_HOME
3. For Apache Sqoop first I got confused about Sqoop Server and Sqoop client , as I am working on single node cluster ( my macbook) so I just took the CDH5 version of Apache Sqoop tarball , unzip the same and then I set the SQOOP_HOME path in .bash_profile file.

Then the expected output I believed was when I will run sqoop help it'll list me all the sqoop command but that didn't happen. So i thought the problem is with bash_profile , so again I checked and found
`PATH = $SQOOP_HOME\bin:$PATH` , i did set the line in the end of _bash_profile.

So I tried to run the sqoop server here

```
sqoop_installation_path/bin/sqoop server start
```

some output came , then I tried to run

```
sqoop_installation_path/bin/sqoop help
```

*still same , I am not getting sqoop help in my console so naturally sqoop import export nothing is working , all throws same error no command found..*

I searched a lot , did change several things but couldn't resolve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using sqoop2 which has different server and client elements. Try using sqoop1, the user guide is here: http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_sqoop_releases

Downloads are available from here: http://sqoop.apache.org/